# jquery loading image not stopping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a weird problem i am making a jquery mobile template and the ajax loadin image pops up and does not go i don't know why its stuck here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="./style/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./style/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="./style/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./style/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./style/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function signin(){
    var name = $('#user');
    var pass = $('#pass');
    if(name.val() == "" || pass.val() == ""){
        alert("Please enter your username and password");
        name.val('');
        pass.val('');
    }else{
        $.post("http://localhost/teezy/api/index.php?name="+name.val()+"&pass="+pass.val(), function(data){
            if(data == "Wrong Username or Password"){
            alert(data);
            name.val('');
            pass.val('');
            }else{
            $(document.location.replace('index2.html'));
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="login" data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="user">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="" placeholder="Username" />
      <label for="pass">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="" placeholder="Password" />
      <button data-icon="check" onclick="signin()">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>&copy; TITLE</h4>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and it is on every page until i click something.

Comment: It looks like you are including both the minified and unminified versions of the mobile style sheet and javascript. Have you tried not doing that?

Comment: woop thanks... how did i forgot that?